# How to invoke visual C++ methods in c#.net?

Tags: visual-c++, c#-4.0

I have a CPP project. I want to use the cpp methods in the C# which is the client.
I searched and found related links on this. In one of the link, After creating the dll of cpp project, by importing this dll to c#, the problem will be solved. But it doesn't happened. I am new to this cpp invoving with c#.

Thanks in advnce.

Comment: There are numerous questions about this on SO. Two solutions are PInvoke and COM Interop (keywords).

Comment: please provide good links on this.

Comment: Please show good prior searches...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574801/call-c-library-in-c-sharp , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550031/cant-call-c-function-from-c-sharp , http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+pinvoke , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626793/compile-c-lib-files-make-them-dll-for-c-sharp-enviroment , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106289/using-com-dll-in-c-sharp etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

Refer

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/article.php/c4217

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/texblog/archive/2007/04/05/linking-native-c-into-c-applications.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeremykuhne/archive/2005/06/11/428363.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deeptanshuv/archive/2005/06/26/432870.aspx